# Screensaver does not offer option to use any photos

Tags: screensaver

On iMac with Yosemite, my screensaver has lost the option to use photos.  Where there should be an option to select a photos folder there is only a bar "Screen Saver Options" i.e. color, speed etc of the cg saver options which are still available.  If I try to select a photo option e.g. "Photo Mobile" I get an endless rotating color disk.

I have tried reinstalling Yosemite, deleting all screensaver-related plists in preferences and rebuilding iPhoto, with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

*[[Note: if you see a spinning "Beachball" it may be that your photo library is quite large so the processor may need time to display everything.  You may find that placing photos you wish to display in a folder stored outside of **iPhoto** or the **Photos** app will improve performance.]]*

Assuming you have photos in a folder or imported into the **Photos** app, this procedure should help.

- Go to **System Preferences**
- Select **Desktop & Screen Saver**
- Select the **Screen Saver** tab
- Choose one of the photo type screen saver options such as **Floating** or **Reflections**
- From the **Source** pop-up menu select your source from **Photos** or a folder with your pictures by selecting **Choose Folder...** or **Photo Library...**

[image: Screen Saver Settings Yosemite]

[image: Photos selection]